# how to change particles' position when a mouse pointer comes over an element in VertexShader

Tags: three.js, glsl, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I made interaction text particles with shaderMaterial.

I passed the cursor’s position as a uniform and displace the particles based on their distance from it. It works, but there is a problem, which is that particles are displaced before the cursor on the element.

here is my vertex shader.

```
uniform vec3 uMouse;
uniform float uSize;
uniform float uPixelRatio;
uniform float uTime;

attribute float aScale;
attribute float pindex;
attribute float angle;

    void main()
    {
        /**
         * Position
         */
         //local
        float rndz = (random(pindex) + snoise(vec2(pindex * 0.1, uTime * 0.1)));
    
        vec3 particlePosition = (modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0)).xyz;
        
        float distanceToMouse = pow(1. - clamp(length(uMouse.xy - particlePosition.xy) -.03, -4., 1.), 2.5);
    
        particlePosition.x -= distanceToMouse * 0.5 * rndz * cos(angle);
        particlePosition.y -= distanceToMouse * 0.5 * rndz * sin(angle);
    
        //camera
    
        vec4 viewPosition = viewMatrix * vec4(particlePosition, 1.);
    
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewPosition;

        //size
        gl_PointSize = uSize * aScale * uPixelRatio;}
```

this image is the problem in the beginning.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZJ7l.png)